# taking long time to boot ubuntu 16.04 while screen is flickering

Tags: 16.04, screen

I am using ubuntu 16.04 in a Dell inspitor 15(3000 series) laptop. When I switch on it, the screen starts to flicker and takes an indefinite time to start. After restarting it many times it starts and it shows some error report. Please help to sort out this. Thank you.[screenshot of error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB20V.png)

Comment: Did it ever work correctly? Have you considered upgrading to 18.04?

Comment: Yes I had tried to upgrade it. But I found 18.04.01 more problematic. There also screen flickering problem remained, my laptop wifi started to show problem, some keys of my keyboard ( delete button and insert button) got automatically pressed. So I switched back to ubuntu 16.04.05.

Comment: Smells like faulty hardware. What have you done to prove that your hardware works properly?

Comment: I had asked one hardware expert about this. He verified the status of all hardware parts in the boot menu. I don't know exactly what he did but as per his opinion, there is no hardware issue but the issue is in OS.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start investigating this would be to look through the systemd journal after it has eventually booted for any errors which may be adding to or causing the issue.

You can view this with `sudo journalctl -xe` in a terminal. You can scroll up and down with your arrow keys. Quite often there will be errors in there that are mostly harmless so it will take some investigating.

When I do this I tend to copy the generic parts of any error messages I find into Google as about 99% of the time someone will have already experienced it and hopefully found a fix!

Comment: I checked this. I found no error message in output.

Comment: You may need to scroll quite far to see anything you're interested in, might want to use grep to search through it?